# Composer package vendors for TYPO3 extensions ending with "ext" don't get symlinked into public/_assets on TYPO3 v12.4

Tags: typo3, typo3-12.x

When the composer package vendor of a TYPO3 extension ends with "ext", the "Resources/Public" directory of the extension does not get symlinked into public/_assets.

Example: typo3_ext/my_extension

This is because of this line:

vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Composer/PackageArtifactBuilder.php:264

```php
if (str_contains($path, 'ext/' . $extensionKey) || !file_exists($fileSystemResourcesPath)) {
    continue;
}
```

When it is changed to this, it works for me:

```php
if (str_contains($path, '/ext/' . $extensionKey) || !file_exists($fileSystemResourcesPath)) {
    continue;
}
```

Since `$path` contains the full path, I guess that change should be OK?

TYPO3 12.4.4

Comment: sounds like a bug, I added it to the issue tracker https://forge.typo3.org/issues/101590 - thanks for your detailed report!